# How do I fix "missing operating system" when Windows partition was marked as biosgrub?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a MacBook pro and have downloaded bootcamp Windows 7, and was trying to dual boot Ubuntu. I got it to download and start and went into the installation setup and it asked me to do something with the partitions and I was messing around and accidentally marked the Windows folder as biosgrub.

It then froze and I forced it to shutdown, but when it rebooted, it said `missing operating system` and I can't boot Windows anymore. I can get into system recovery and can still see the files, but it just won't boot. I could restore OS X and buy another Windows disk, but I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: You can run gparted from grml or Gparted live https://gparted.org/livehd.php

Comment: Was it just the bios_grub flag? or reformat as bios_grub is totally unformatted space. And if grub installed its core.img into it, it would have erased part of Windows. If not you may be able to remove bios_grub flag, make sure partition is NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve an issue like this with [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).  It will scan for "lost" operating systems and add them to GRUB.

Comment: I can't get into a terminal besides the Apple recovery terminal. As soon as it boots, it said missing operating system and I have to force shutdown before I can do anything else.

Comment: Please see the instructions I linked on Boot-Repair.   Both options involve booting into a live environment.  You will need to prepare a USB (or optical disc) with the utility [preinstalled with boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

Or you can follow the second option to do it manually within a live Ubuntu USB or disc.